# After async/await change, using Dispatcher.Invoke() doesn't solve CollectionView changes other than Dispatcher thread

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I made a change to my app to load data (using async/await) on background threads while the app opens. Now, after the app has fully loaded, when trying to update a bound property, I'm getting this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support
>   changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the
>   Dispatcher thread.

This code was working before the async/await changes updated that property in the first place. I tried adding Dispatcher.Invoke() around the code, but I got the same error:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    this._customVariableGroups[index] = savedGroup;
});
```

Since this field was originally updated on a background thread, is that causing problems with updating it from the main thread? Note, in the threads window in Visual Studio, this code is executing on the main thread. I'm not sure what else to do to get this to work.

This is the field:

```
private ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup> _customVariableGroups;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your collection view is being created on a background thread, which is not a good idea in general.

If you're loading data using `async`/`await` (and your data loading supports asynchronous operations), then you shouldn't need to use background threads.

Comment: @BobHorn: The field needs to be constructed on the UI thread. It's best if your data loading is fully `async` (e.g., using `async` EF6 queries if you're loading from a database, or `HttpClient` if you're loading from a web service) - that way there's no need for `Task.Run` (or any background threads) at all. However, it may be easier to just keep the data loading as it currently is (blocking, on a background thread), and have it *return* the data to the UI. Just return "regular" data like `T[]` or `List<T>` and not `ObservableCollection<T>`.